# What happened to my clownfish?

Tags: aquarium, fish, death, clownfish

I’ve had a nanotank for about 2 years now, and today something really strange happened. Yesterday, my clowns were totally fine, swimming and eating like normal. Today I went to feed them this morning and only one of my clowns showed up. So, I started looking around my tank and found a SKELETON. Upon further inspection, it seems to be the remains of my other clownfish. I only have another clownfish and a Blenny in there now, with a cleanup crew as well. Any ideas of what could have happened?

Comment: Most likely the clownfish jumped from the nanotak.

Answer (score 3):

If a fish dies whatever reason, it's not really unusual for tank mates, especially 'cleanup crew' type creatures, to make really quick work of the remains.  It doesn't really give any clues as to the cause of death, but eating any dead fish they come across is natural behavior for many fish, and you can't really assume that they killed the clownfish in this case.

You should keep an eye on the usual suspects (diseases, water quality, etc) as far as determining how your clown died and preventing any more losses-- it was almost surely not murder.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it was the natural course of life, the fish died on its own and the cleanup crew as you call it ate the remands(the corps) just like lions and cheetahs and tigers and leopards they eat there pray.